# extract special values in an output files into a single file

Tags: command-line

I have several output files as [file-here](https://files.fm/u/56hvagjc), in which in the front of an expression ("mass is") there is a number (value) that here equals to `55.25`.

The files are in different folders but I wish to collect all of value of masses in one `.dat` file as a column of various masses.

How can I do this aim by a command line!?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that all the files are somewhere below your home directory you could do:

```
grep -R '^mass is' $HOME | sed 's/.*mass is //' >> $HOME/results.dat
```

If the files are elsewhere in some folder tree replace the first part by

```
grep -R '^mass is' some_folder | sed ....
```

Comment: If possible please create a single folder containing above file or something else and please work with the address of that file. Because I am confused by the above command line such I could not use that. (I could not understand what should I do instead $ Home!!)

Comment: `$HOME` (written exactly like that) is a shell variable containing the name of your home folder. This is `/home/<your_username>` where your_username is the name you chose while installing Ubuntu. Just open a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T and enter the above command. If your file are located elsewhere give me some examples of where they are.

Comment: thank you so much, I am far away machine with which I was working, if I face to a problem I will ask you. Thank you again